# how to use joins to get back a single query selected elements from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have (in Rails 3.2.13):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_event_login_logouts
end

class AppEventLoginLogout < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

and would like to get back something like:

```
AppEventLoginLogoug.select("id, type, users.email").joins(:user)
```

basically id, type from app_event_login_logouts and email from users but this doesn't seem to be working. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out following code:

```
ret = User.joins(:app_event_login_logouts).select('app_event_login_logouts.id, app_event_login_logouts.type, users.email')
ret.first.id # will return app_event_login_logouts.id
ret.first.email # will return users.email
...
```

Comment: Thx,why doesn't the reverse work? like AppEventLoginLogout.joins(:user)?

Comment: No difference. Did you try that? in me machine it's working. Try out this if not `AppEventLoginLogout.joins(:user).select('app_event_login_logouts.id, app_event_login_logouts.type, users.email')`

Comment: thx, that works. I thought I'd tried that combo . need some coffee ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
AppEventLoginLogoug.find(:all, 
                         {:include => [:users],
                          :select => ['id', 'type', 'users.email']})
```

I also checked the [apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class#109-Avoiding-duplicate-results-when-you-do-a-join) and found something like that:

```
result= AppEventLoginLogoug.find(:all, 
                                 :conditions => ['condition_here'], 
                                 :joins => [:users], 
                                 :select => 'whatever_to_select'
                                 :order => 'your.order')
```

Comment: I think this will work:     `@logins_logouts=AppEventLoginLogout.select(["id","user_id, created_at, users.email"]).includes(:user)`